# Evenly distribute number X to number Y

Tags: javascript, integer, divide

So.. to best describe what I want to achieve using either JavaScript or HTML5 I will try to illustrate with an example:

Say I have 100 boxes lined up.
I want to add another 30 boxes, and I want them evenly distributed.

If you just divide 100 by 30 you end up with having to add a box every 3,333 boxes, which is ofc not doable in the real world.

The end result I am looking for is for instance "Count 2 boxes, add one, count 3 boxes, add one, repeat 10 times, count 4 boxes, add one, repeat 9 times, count 3 boxes, add one, repeat 10 times, count last 2 boxes"

Hopefully, the example makes sense.

Comment: Are you stacking the 30 boxes on top of the 100 boxes? To evenly distribute the 30 boxes you're on the right track. Store the product of 100/30 as a float. The position of each box can be calculated as p = Math.round((100/30) * i); where p is the position and i is current iteration. If you add more boxes later you have to recalculate the position of 30 boxes along with the new boxes to keep everything evenly distributed

Comment: The boxes were just to try to give a visualization. :) Another one could be "I have 100 green apples lined up, and want to add 30 red apples evenly distributed on the line", the actual use for it is making a calculator for the wife who loves knitting. At some points she has to increase the number of stitches, and I am basically trying to get something working with two form fields where she enters the number of stitches currently, and the no of stitches she has to add, and then it calculates as illustrated

Will look into Math.round, looks like it might just do the trick when I figure it out.

Comment: Did some testing with Math.round() and it seems like it is not doing it quite right for me. Using your formula it will just alternate with adding one box/apple/stitch every 3rd twice, then 4th (which makes sense, as it just adds up the 0.33 decimal on the two first with the third making it 4)

With more thought, I think I have to find a way to first find how many boxes to have at the start and end to ensure the new boxes are centered (in example you start adding after 2 boxes and leave 2 at the end), then divide the remaining 96 into 3 even numbers where two are equal, in this case, 30-36-30